# Send payment in multiple destination account by using customer card id in stripe

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

```
  Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_j26LHmQkliAum0N5KRNG9gVG");

  $token = Stripe::tokens()->create([
    'card' => [
      'number'    => '4242424242424242',
      'exp_month' => '11',
      'cvc'       => '123',
      'exp_year'  => '2021',
    ],
  ]);
  $charge = \Stripe::charges()->create([
    "amount" => 10,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token['id'],
    "destination" => array(
    "amount" => 8,
    "account" => "acct_19xa8WLv4n7LNSRg",
  ),
  ]);
  $transfer = Stripe::transfers()->create([
    "amount" => 8,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source_transaction" => $charge['id'],
    "destination" => "acct_19xa8WLv4n7LNSRg",
  ]);
```

We need to send payment in two destination account but it's sending all the payment in setApiKey account.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you should never create a card token server-side. This means that you get the card numbers on your server which has some serious [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/) implications.

You should use [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements) or [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) client-side to send the card details to Stripe directly and get a unique card token (tok_XXX) that you'd then send safely to your server to create the charge.

As for the error, your code is transferring the amount twice here. First, you create the charge for $0.10 and transfer $0.08 to the connected account automatically and then you create a new transfer to the same account for $0.08 again.

Since you can't transfer more than the original charge amount, it would transfer the full $0.10 to the connected account in that case.

You need to correct multiple things here:
* You should pass amount in cents. To charge $10 USD you would pass `amount: 1000`.
* You want to pass a *different account id* in the Transfer creation if you're sending funds to a different account.
* You want to create the charge on the platform without the `destination` if you're transferring funds to multiple accounts. Instead use `transfer_group` as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).

You likely want to talk to Stripe's support team directly for follow up questions as this is more about their product than code.